# Экспорт списка Issues из YouTrack

Tags: jetbrains, youtrack, bug-tracking

Необходимо сделать отчёт по списку найденных ошибок и созданных задач (issues) в YouTrack - как можно реализовать это в максимально удобоваримом виде, например excel-таблице или pdf-файле?

Нашёл возможность экспорта базы данных YouTrack, но она, судя по всему, пригодна только для импорта на другой сервер или баг-трекер, а мне нужно свести все найденные ошибки и их описания в один файл, удобный для просмотра. Буду крайне благодарен за помощь или хотя бы подсказку в каком направлении копать :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покурил документацию на английском и нашёл как экспортировать задачи из поиска в CSV (для импорта в excel) или HTML. В окне задач нужно открыть список "отчёты" и только из этого списка, но не из большого меню с отчётами - доступен экспорт в 2 поддерживаемых формата. В последней версии YouTrack это выглядит следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Так же можно создать отчёт и скачать его результаты в CSV
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]